# Untar a file and find the links(short/full) in the text

Tags: python, json, r, csv

I am currently working on tar file, which is nearly a 100 MB file.
I need to see the links in the text and find the comments/likes/shares for the links.
I could untar the file and save it as json using Python, But on converting it to csv  using

```
import csv, json, sys

input = open(input.json)
data = json.load(input)
input.close()

output = csv.writer(output.csv)

output.writerow(data[0].keys()) 
for row in data:
output.writerow(row.values())
```

I am left with 1kb file
Is there any way to do without converting it to json?
Or using R?

Comment: why are you using `output = csv.writer(sys.stdout)`? Also what is `input = open(input.json)`?

Comment: Input.json is the json file I am using to convert to csv and csv.writer(output.csv) is the destination file